# Swapping mesh linked to armature

Tags: animation, armature, parent

I'm newer to blender and am at a bit of a standstill.

I've imported a viewport animation from an FPS game, and I want to change the arms that are linked to the animation. The arms I want to use with the animation are also ported from a game and have their own skeleton. How would I go about swapping out these things?

I'm very new to this. if there's more information that you may need then I will provide it upon request, any help is much appreciated!!

(The top image contains the mesh I want to use the animation with)

[image: Mesh i want to use]
[image: Current viewarms with the animation i want to use]

Comment: remove the object and armature that you won't use, put the armature in its reste pose (in Pose mode select all and Alt R, Alt S and Alt G), it will be better if the rest pose is a T pose, align the character with the armature, if the arms have not the same pose you can use the Pose brush in Sculp mode, join the arms to the rest of your character, parent the character to the armature With Automatic Weights